# Dynamically Building LINQ-To-Entities Where Clause

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

How can I build the where clause dynamically, Some time the `OwnerID` will be zero only `itemID` and `LocationID`will be provided as the search criteria, in that case the LINQ should be

```
(from s in repository.ItemOwners.Include("OwnerDetails")
 where s.ItemId == searchCriteria.ItemID && 
       s.OwnerDetails.LocationId == searchCriteria.LocationID
 select new { s.OwnerDetails.OwnerName, s.OwnerDetails.MobNumber }).ToList();
```

Some time the `OwnerID` and `ItemId` will be zero then only the `LocationID` will be provided as the search criteria, in that case the LINQ should be

```
(from s in repository.ItemOwners.Include("OwnerDetails")
 where s.OwnerDetails.LocationId == searchCriteria.LocationID
 select new { s.OwnerDetails.OwnerName, s.OwnerDetails.MobNumber }).ToList();
```

Some time the whole `OwnerID`, `ItemID` and `LocationID` will be provided as the search criteria, then the LINQ will be like this

```
(from s in repository.ItemOwners.Include("OwnerDetails")
 where s.OwnerId == searchCriteria.OwnerID && 
       s.ItemId == searchCriteria.ItemID && 
       s.OwnerDetails.LocationId == searchCriteria.LocationID
 select new { s.OwnerDetails.OwnerName, s.OwnerDetails.MobNumber }).ToList();
```

Here only the `where` clause is changing, Please help me to solve. How I can I build the `where` clause dynamically (Please note, here I am having a navigation property which is `OwnerDetails.LocationId`).

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do it by using method-based query. You can add the conditions one at a time and call `Select` and `ToList` at the end:

```
// Where(x => true) might not be necessary, you can try skipping it.
var query = repository.ItemOwners.Include("OwnerDetails").Where(x => true);

if (searchCriteria.OwnerID != null)
    query = query.Where(s => s.OwnerID == searchCriteria.OwnerID);
if (searchCriteria.ItemID != null)
    query = query.Where(s => s.ItemID == searchCriteria.ItemID);
if (searchCriteria.OwnerID != null)
    query = query.Where(s => s..OwnerDetails.LocationId == searchCriteria.LocationID);

var results = query.Select(s => new { s.OwnerDetails.OwnerName, s.OwnerDetails.MobNumber }).ToList();
```

Comment: This is the method that is the most readable and correct to do in this case

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is just check the zero condition in the Where clause:

```
(from s in repository.ItemOwners.Include("OwnerDetails")
where (searchCriteria.OwnerID == 0 || s.OwnerId == searchCriteria.OwnerID) && 
(searchCriteria.ItemID == 0 || s.ItemId == searchCriteria.ItemID) && 
s.OwnerDetails.LocationId == searchCriteria.LocationID
select new { s.OwnerDetails.OwnerName, s.OwnerDetails.MobNumber }).ToList();
```